# problem with the gradle syncing in android studio "earthquake app"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I imported the earthquake app which is an example from Udacity teaching platform in the android basics course , after the Gradle finished syncing , I got this message "Gradle sync failed: Don't know how to build models for org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle.DefaultGradleBuild@30071c7d
Consult IDE log for more details "

also, in the xml file , all the attributes are not allowed and are shown in red !!!

Can anyone help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not add a dependency in your Gradle(module app) to add the dependency check image here >>
[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXzbU.png)

Comment: thank you,  @kneelon ,the problem was with the Android studio version , so I downloaded another version than the one I had